# How to add queries to Post request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, post, request

Hi I'm trying to add queries to this Post request in Node.js. I'm not sure how to do so.
Here is the Post request code that I am using,

```
    var options = {
  host: 'ws.ispeech.org',
  port: 80,
  path: '/api/rest/1.5',
  method: 'POST',
};

var http = require('http');
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is part of the URL, which the node.js options object calls the "path".  So you can simply add the query string to the path:

```javascript
var query = 'foo=bar&abc=123';
var options = {
  host: 'ws.ispeech.org',
  port: 80,
  path: '/api/rest/1.5' + '?' + query,
  method: 'POST',
};
```

Note that there is also a ["querystring" module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/querystring.html) which will encode object propertly/values for you:

```javascript
var query = querystring.stringify({foo:'bar', abc:123});
// query => "foo=bar&abc=123"
```